# Proof that using adjacency matrix for bipartite testing has Ω(n^2)

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, proof, bipartite

so in one of my lectures I came across the proof for:

:  algorithm that determines if a graph is bipartite
that has as its input an undirected graph  = (, ) represented
as an  ×  adjacency matrix, has the running time of Ω(^2)

We assume an algorithm ALG which test for bipartiteness (returns either true or false). And we also assume we have a graph 0 = (, 0) with  = {1,2, … , } and 0 = { 1,  : 2 ≤  ≤ } (as this is a star it is a bipartite graph)

Within the proof there's a step saying:
"For a given algorithm ALG, we will construct another graph 1 st: if ALG performs less than (−1)C2 accesses to the adjacency matrix  of 0,
then ALG will not distinguish between 0 and 1, and 1 is not bipartite."

My question is what does (n-1)C2 accesses mean. Is it saying that for example if we have a different V = {A,B,C,D} then ALG will look at all node pairs except for the ones between D and the other nodes ?

Sorry if this isn't clear this proof really confused me.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/ is where this should be posted, and will also most likely get you an answer (compared to here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

G<sub>0</sub> is an n-vertex [star graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_(graph_theory)). It's bipartite, but if you add any other edge to it, the resulting graph is not. There are n−1 choose 2 = (n−1)(n−2)/2 = Ω(n<sup>2</sup>) other edges that we can add. Every correct algorithm must check every single one in order to verify that G<sub>0</sub> is bipartite.